# Yii how to highlight the current menu item

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I used the following code to display the menu items.

Here by default the 'Home' link should be activated. So that i used the code

`active' => $this->id =='default' ? true : false`

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
     'linkLabelWrapper' => 'span',
    'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('post/index'),'active'=>$this->id=='default'?true:false),
    array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('site/page', 'view'=>'about'),'active'=>$this->id=='about'?true:false),
    array('label'=>'Test', 'url'=>array('site/page', 'view'=>'test')),
    array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('site/contact')),
    array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
    array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    ),
    ));
```

I referred the url http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#activateItems-detail 
But i dont know how to use these parameters. Please help

Comment: The activeItems by default is turned on. Did you check your HTML for `class="active"` ? Even with `'active'=>$this->id=='default'?true:false` removed from items ?

Comment: Yes i checked the html the class="active" is not displayed

Comment: It works properly on my sites without needing to specifically setup the active attribute. You might look into the activateParent attribute (I forget its name exactly).  Are you getting active on some of the sub pages but not all?

Answer (score 6):

Not the Yii way, but the (simpler) jQuery way:

```
// find menu-item associated with this page and make current:
$('a').each(function(index, value) { 
    if ($(this).prop("href") === window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("current-page");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you give will be typically found inside a [view](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view). The documentation for view states that

> Inside the view script, we can access the controller instance using
>   `$this`. We can thus pull in any property of the controller by
>   evaluating `$this->propertyName` in the view.

So, we have established that in the current context, `$this->id` refers to the [`CController::id`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#id-detail) property. This id will typically be the prefix of your controller's class name. For example, inside `MyController` you will have `$this->id == "my"`.

With all this in mind, you can now tell that `active` will be `true` if and only if the current view is rendered from inside a controller named `DefaultController`. However, from the `url` property of that menu item we see that the associated controller for that action (assuming default routing) is `PostController`. So the `$this->id == "default"` idea is faulty.

If you want to make the "Home" item active whenever *any* action in your `PostController` is running, you should change this to `$this->id == "post"`. Normally it should not be necessary to do this, because the `activateItems` property (which defaults to `true`) used with default routing will take into account both the controller id *and* the current action to determine which menu item to make active.

Answer (score 3):

if you have some advanced link structure, put method below in Controller

```
/**
 * Checks if the current route matches with given routes
 * @param array $routes
 * @return bool
 */
public function isActive($routes = array())
{
    $routeCurrent = '';
    if ($this->module !== null) {
        $routeCurrent .= sprintf('%s/', $this->module->id);
    }
    $routeCurrent .= sprintf('%s/%s', $this->id, $this->action->id);
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $pattern = sprintf('~%s~', preg_quote($route));
        if (preg_match($pattern, $routeCurrent)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//usage
'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Some Label', 'url'=>array('some/route'),'active'=>$this->isActive(array(
        'some/route',
        'another/route',        
    )),    
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this way:

```
array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('site/contact'), 'active'=>strpos(Yii::app()->request->requestUri, Yii::app()->createUrl('site/contact'))===0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu will work as we use default pages as site/contact, site/login
But many times it will not work for the module url.

suppose i have module user and i had login action in login controller, so i can do below thing form menu as how menu item gets active defined below.

```
array('label'=>Yii::t('frontend','Login'), 'url'=>array('/user/login/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest), // Working, Login tag activated on login page

array('label'=>Yii::t('frontend','Login'), 'url'=>array('/user/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest), // Not working, Login tag not activated on login page
```

So, we can have problem to beautify url..

Answer (score 0):

For yiistarterkit just add this code in the _base.php file:

```
function isActive($routes = array())
{
    if (Yii::$app->requestedRoute == "" && count($routes) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    $routeCurrent = Yii::$app->requestedRoute;
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $pattern = sprintf('~%s~', preg_quote($route));
        if (preg_match($pattern, $routeCurrent)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then use:

```
echo Nav::widget([
'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-left'],
'items' => [
    ['label' => \Yii::t('frontend', 'Home'), 'url' => ['/'], 'active'=>isActive()],
    ['label' => \Yii::t('frontend', 'Services'), 'url' => ['/services'], 'active'=>isActive(['services'])],
]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take as a base the file yiisoft/yii2-boostrap/nav.php function renderItem():

```
...
if ($this->activateItems && $active) {
    Html::addCssClass($options, 'active');
}       
return Html::tag('li', Html::a($label, $url, $linkOptions) . $items, $options);
```

And modify $option on $linkOption for a link.

```
Html::addCssClass($linkOptions, 'active');
```

As result active class will be added to a.class, instead li.class