# Using Controller method from a widget's view in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-widgets

I have a simple task that I want to achieve - I have a navbar widget and I want to add "active" class to links that leading to the currently displayed page.

Cetver's answer @ [Yii how to highlight the current menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802662/yii-how-to-highlight-the-current-menu-item) gives me a pretty method that I need to put in a Controller class.  It works like a charm in controllers and views.

I do need to use it in my widget's view... how do I access it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: CWidget->controller returns the current controller.  So: $this->controller->isActive(); can be used in the widget class or its view.